# How to draw a five pointed star?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a five-pointed star, as in the following figure.

[image]

I used the following commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

\draw[ultra thick,shift={(0,0)},rotate=18] (3.86,11.90)--(-10.12,-7.35);

\draw [ultra thick,shift={(0,0)},rotate=18] (3.86,11.90)--(3.86,-11.90);

\draw [ultra thick,shift={(0,0)},rotate=18] (-10.12,7.35)--(3.86,-11.90);

\draw [ultra thick,shift={(0,0)},rotate=18] (-10.12,7.35)--(12.51,0);

\draw [ultra thick,shift={(0,0)},rotate=18]  (-10.12,-7.35)--(12.51,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to complete the figure?

Comment: after 90 questions, isn't it time to have a look at [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)?

Comment: Samcarter, OK! Next time I'll look carefully to get it right. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to complete it, but it's very simple with `pstricks` without having to fight with vertices coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=53pt, svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-poly, pst-eucl}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex -shell-escape TeXLive, MacTeX)
                          %% or pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX)

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, dimen=inner, linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture}
\PstStarFive[PolyName=A]
\uput[r](A1){A} \uput[u](A2){B}
\uput[l](A3){C}\uput[dl](A4){D} \uput[dr](A5){E}
\psset{PointSymbol=none}
\pstInterLL[ PosAngle=180]{A2}{A4}{A3}{A5}{I}
\pstInterLL{A1}{A4}{A2}{A5}{J}
\pstInterLL[PosAngle=40]{A1}{A3}{A2}{A5}{K}
\pspolygon[linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=LimeGreen!60!YellowGreen!35!](A1)(A3)(I)(J)
\psline(J)(A1)(A3)(I)
\psline[linewidth=0.4pt](K)(I)(J)
 \end{pspicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with TikZ using relative polar coordinates. The star defines coordinates for each tip and corner, which can be used for later drawing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{3} % distance center to tip
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cc}{\ct*sin(18)/sin(126)} % distance center to corner (sine rule)
% star
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0)
    +(90-0*36:\ct) coordinate(T1)
    foreach[evaluate=\x as \nc using int((\x+1)/2),   % number for corner coordinates
            evaluate=\x as \nt using int((\x+1)/2+1)] % number for tip coordinates
        \x in {1,3,...,9}{
        -- +(90-\x*36:\cc) coordinate(C\nc) -- +({90-(\x+1)*36}:\ct) coordinate(T\nt)}
    -- cycle;
\node[above=1cm] at (T1) {star only};
% star
\draw[ultra thick] (7,0)
    +(90-0*36:\ct) coordinate(T1)
    foreach[evaluate=\x as \nc using int((\x+1)/2),   % number for corner coordinates
            evaluate=\x as \nt using int((\x+1)/2+1)] % number for tip coordinates
        \x in {1,3,...,9}{
        -- +(90-\x*36:\cc) coordinate(C\nc) -- +({90-(\x+1)*36}:\ct) coordinate(T\nt)}
    -- cycle;
% the rest
\draw[ultra thick] (C2) -- (C3) -- (C4);
\draw[ultra thick,fill=green] (T5) -- (C1) -- (C4) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick,fill=green] (C4) -- (C1) -- (T2) -- (C2) -- (C4);

\node[above=1cm] at (T1) {complete};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```