# TikZ and FIFA WorldCup 2018: Flags of Nations

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I am a kind of TikZ addict, and also be a fan of football. This time - WorldCup 2018 - is nice change of relaxing by drawing flags of 32 football teams by pure TikZ or TikZ-based codes. Some are easy (like the Japan flag ^^), some are somehow difficult! Please join and/or suggest me!

Let me start with the South-Korean flag. In its code, I like the way of (i) drawing the Yin Yang symbols and the 4 black trigrams via only one parameter \YYrotation; (ii) using scope, foreach, and (iii) using a trick of coloring black/white trigrams with a little bit bigger line width. I first draw trigrams at (0,0), then use rotation and shift to move to the corners. Description of the South-Korean flag can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_South_Korea

[image]

The followings are the TikZ codes for the South-Korean flag.

```
% Description of The SOUTH-KOREAN FLAG 
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_South_Korea
% A rectangle: width = 2/3 length,
% the Yin Yang symbol (red above, blue below) at center,
% the 4 black trigrams at 4 corners.

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{7.5}  % a half of the length 
\def\b{5}    % a half of the width 
\def\r{1.25} % radius of the Yin/Yang symbol 

% radius of the big circle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2*\r} 
% the rotation angle of Yin/Yang/trigrams
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YYrotation}{atan(3/2)} 

% the whole rectangle of the flag
\path (-\a,-\b) rectangle (\a,\b); 

% the Yin Yang symbol: draw, then rotate
\begin{scope}[rotate=\YYrotation]
\fill[red] (0,\R) arc (90:-90:\R) arc(-90:90:\r) arc(270:90:\r);
\fill[blue] (0,-\R) arc (270:90:\R) arc(90:270:\r) arc(90:-90:\r);
\end{scope}

% the spring trigram (the above-left corner)
\begin{scope}[rotate=\YYrotation,shift={(0,4.6)},line width=.42 cm]
\foreach \j in {0,5/8,-5/8} \draw (-5/4,\j)--(5/4,\j);
\end{scope}

% the autumn trigram (the below-left corner)
\begin{scope}[rotate=-\YYrotation,shift={(0,-4.6)},line width=.42 cm]
\foreach \j in {0,5/8,-5/8} \draw (-5/4,\j)--(5/4,\j);
\draw[white,line width=.44 cm] (-5/48,0)--(5/48,0);
\end{scope}

% the winter trigram (the above-right corner)
\begin{scope}[rotate=-\YYrotation,shift={(0,4.6)},line width=.42 cm]
\foreach \j in {0,5/8,-5/8} \draw (-5/4,\j)--(5/4,\j);
\foreach \j in {5/8,-5/8} \draw[white,line width=.44 cm] (-5/48,\j)--(5/48,\j);
\end{scope}

% the summer trigram (the below-right corner)
\begin{scope}[rotate=\YYrotation,shift={(0,-4.6)},line width=.42 cm]
\foreach \j in {0,5/8,-5/8} \draw (-5/4,\j)--(5/4,\j);
\foreach \j in {0,5/8,-5/8} \draw[white,line width=.44 cm] (-5/48,\j)--(5/48,\j);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some of the flags are already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18516/121799), I think. And probably it is easier to try to find the svg files on the net and use them.

Comment: @marmot: I know, but I just want  flags with TikZ codes, not by inputing some avaiable svg, png, files

Comment: I suggest waiting until the final and drawing 2. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn So sad that egreg cannot contribute Italy :-(

Comment: waiting for Argentina in the upcoming match. Surely I will draw the Argentina flag if they are in the next round

Comment: I once did the Argentina flag in something tikz based, but I lost the source code: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7529/who-plans-to-go-to-tug-2018-in-rio-de-janeiro/7548#comment22551_7548

Comment: My tikz-fu is only good for Japan 

Comment: I added "fun" tag! Please vote for me, so I have enough points to do that kind of things ^^

Comment: @BlackMild You can always tag your own questions using existing tags just by editing them.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner \fbox{\Huge\color{red}.}

Comment: I guess I'm the only one who finds these sorts of attention-grabbing highly-upvoted "fun" drawing questions to be extremely stale.

Comment: NOW I know why you started with the Korean flag. ;-)

Comment: Just a typo, but the comment "the Yin Yang symbol (red above, green below) at center," should be "blue below"

Comment: @frarugi87: I corrected that typo! thank you!

Comment: just waiting for Croatian flag tikzpuctire ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here one for Peru, The normal flag of my country is simple, what happens is that for this 2018 tournament, they have used the flag with a shield, so in this post I will try to complete it even with the shield and the frame style that they have given it, on the official page of FIFA.

Although my country has already been eliminated but hopefully at least winning its last game.

UPDATE: Finishig the tikz drawing using decorations markings library.
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% By J. Leon V. Share as Beerware philosophy
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{D1BA87}
\definecolor{Redper}{HTML}{C60C30}
\definecolor{sky}{HTML}{0083C4}
\definecolor{vicug}{HTML}{A84A0E}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[keli]{malayalam}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings,decorations.shapes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Styles
        Laurel/.style={
            draw,
            double=green!50!black,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0.4 and 0.8 step 0.2
                    with {
                        \draw[double=green!50!black,line width=0.5pt](0,0) [out=0,in=135]
                            to ++(0.25,-.1)
                            (0,0) [out=0,in=-90]
                            to ++(0.25,.15);
                        \draw[fill=Redper](0.25,-.1) circle (1.2pt);
                        \draw[fill=Redper](0.25,.15) circle (1.2pt);
                    }
                }
            },
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0.3 and 1 step 0.2
                    with {
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-45,in=180]
                            to ++(0.5,-.1)[out=105,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-45,in=180]
                            to ++(0.5,-.2)[out=105,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=45,in=180]
                            to ++(0.5,.1)[out=-105,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=45,in=180]
                            to ++(0.5,.2)[out=-105,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Palma/.style={
            draw,
            double=green!50!black,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0.3 and 1 step 0.08
                    with {
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-30,in=160]
                            to ++(0.5,-.2)[out=150,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-30,in=160]
                            to ++(0.5,-.3)[out=150,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=30,in=-160]
                            to ++(0.6,.0)[out=-150,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=30,in=-160]
                            to ++(0.6,.1)[out=-150,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=15,in=180]
                            to ++(0.65,-0.1)[out=-180,in=-15]
                            to cycle;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Corona/.style={
            draw,
            double=green!50!black,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0 and 0.95 step 0.1
                    with {
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-45,in=-135]
                            to ++(0.15,0)[out=135,in=45]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-90,in=180]
                            to ++(0.1,-.1)[out=90,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \draw[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=90,in=-180]
                            to ++(0.1,.1)[out=-90,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Quina/.style={
            draw,
            double=green!50!black,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.5
                    with {
                        \fill[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-45,in=-135]
                            to ++(0.08,0)[out=135,in=45]
                            to cycle;
                        \fill[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=-90,in=180]
                            to ++(0.05,-.05)[out=90,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                        \fill[fill=green!50!black](0,0) [out=90,in=-180]
                            to ++(0.05,.05)[out=-90,in=0]
                            to cycle;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    % Image to used to get coordinates. obtained from my country in fifa web page.
    %\node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG1) at (0,8) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{Peru-flag-russia-2018.pdf}};

    \fill[fill=Redper,out=48,in=180] (-6.2,0) 
        to ++(2.5,3.1)
        -- ++(7.45,0)[out=0,in=138]
        to ++(2.5,-3.1)[out=-138,in=0]
        to ++(-2.5,-3.1)
        -- ++(-7.45,0)[out=180,in=-48]
        to cycle;
    \fill[fill=white,even odd rule]
    (0,0)++(-2.05,-3.1) rectangle ++(4.1,6.2);
    \fill[fill=gold,even odd rule]
    [out=48,in=180] (-6.2,0) 
        to ++(2.5,3.1)
        -- ++(7.45,0)[out=0,in=138]
        to ++(2.5,-3.1)[out=-138,in=0]
        to ++(-2.5,-3.1)
        -- ++(-7.45,0)[out=180,in=-48]
        to cycle
    [out=48,in=180] (-6.6,0) 
        to ++(2.6,3.25)
        -- ++(8,0)[out=0,in=138]
        to ++(2.6,-3.25)[out=-138,in=0]
        to ++(-2.6,-3.25)
        -- ++(-8,0)[out=180,in=-48]
        to cycle;

    %Shield W.I.P.

    \draw[color=gold!80!black,line width=2pt,fill=Redper](0,0)++(-0.66,0)[out=-90,in=90]
    to ++(-0.17,-0.46)[out=-90,in=180]
    to ++(0.33,-0.33)[out=0,in=105]
    to ++(.5,-0.2)[out=75,in=180]
    to ++(.5,0.2)[out=0,in=-90]
    to ++(0.33,0.33)[out=90,in=-90]
    to ++(-0.17,0.46);

    \draw[color=gold!80!black,line width=2pt,fill=sky](0,0) --++(-0.66,0)[out=90,in=-30]
    to ++(-0.25,0.4)[out=30,in=-105]
    to ++(0.25,0.35)[out=-20,in=-135]
    to ++(0.66,0.15) -- cycle;

    \draw[color=gold!80!black,line width=2pt,fill=white](0,0)--++(0.66,0)[out=90,in=-150]
    to ++(0.25,0.4)[out=150,in=-75]
    to ++(-0.25,0.35)[out=-160,in=-45]
    to ++(-0.66,0.15) -- cycle;

    \draw[Laurel](0,0)++(-0.7,-1.5)[out=35,in=180]
    to ++(0.7,0.3)[out=0,in=-95]
    to ++(1.3,0.8)[out=85,in=-50]
    to ++(-.3,1.2);%1

    \draw[Palma](0,0)++(0.7,-1.5)[out=145,in=0]
    to ++(-0.7,0.3)[out=180,in=-65]
    to ++(-1.15,0.5)[out=115,in=-120]
    to ++(0,1.5);%1

    \draw[Corona](0,0)++(0,0.9)[out=0,in=-90]
    to ++(0.4,0.25)[out=90,in=0]
    to ++(-0.4,0.25);

    \draw[Corona](0,0)++(0,0.9)[out=180,in=-90]
    to ++(-0.4,0.25)[out=90,in=180]
    to ++(0.4,0.25);

    \draw[double=gold!60!black,line width=0.5pt](0,0)++(0.37,0.04)
    -- ++(0,0.4);

    \draw[Quina](0,0)++(0.37,0.35) coordinate (A)
    -- ++(0,0.2);
    \draw[Quina](A) -- ++(0.12,0.12);
    \draw[Quina](A) -- ++(-0.12,0.12);
    \draw[Quina](A)++(0,-0.15) -- ++(0.12,0.12);
    \draw[Quina](A)++(0,-0.15) -- ++(-0.12,0.12);

    % Draw Vicugna
    \draw[fill=vicug](0,0)++(-0.25,0.1)
    -- ++(0.02,0) -- ++(0.03,0.2)[out=0,in=-90] to ++(0.02,0.2) -- ++(0.06,0) --  ++ (-0.01,0.03)
    -- ++(-0.04,0.02)--  ++ (-0.02,0.02)--  ++ (0,0.05)--  ++ (-0.04,-0.05)--  ++ (-0.01,-0.02)[out=-135,in=0]
    to ++(-0.05,-0.16)[out=165,in=15] to ++(-0.25,0.04)[out=180,in=90] to ++(-0.05,-0.04)[out=180,in=90]
    to ++(-0.02,-0.04)[out=45,in=90] to ++(0.03,-0.03)[out=-90,in=90] to ++(0.04,-0.08)[out=-90,in=90]
    to ++(0.03,-0.06)[out=-90,in=90]to ++(0.02,-0.08) -- ++(0.02,0 )-- ++(0.03,0.15)[out=-90,in=135] to ++(0.15,-0.03)
    -- cycle;

    % Draw Rich Cornus
    \draw[fill=gold](0,0)++(0.5,-0.45)[out=180,in=-90] to ++ (-0.05,0.05)[out=90,in=180] to ++ (0.05,0.05)
    [out=0,in=90] to ++ (0.15,-0.15)[out=-90,in=0] to ++ (-0.18,-0.15) -- ++ (0,0.1)[out=0,in=-90] to ++ (0.1,0.1)
    [out=90,in=0] to ++ (-0.05,0.05)[out=180,in=135] to cycle;
    \foreach \distance in {0,0.4,0.45,...,1}{
        \draw[
            draw=none,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position \distance with {
                    \draw[fill=gold] (0,0) circle (5*\distance pt);
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate}
        ](0,0)++(0.5,-0.45) arc (270:90:0.05)
        arc (90:-90:0.12)[out=180,in=0] to ++(-0.6,0.38)[out=180,in=60] to ++(-0.2,-0.17);
    }

    \foreach \distance in {0,1,...,40}{
        \draw[fill=gold!] (0,0)++(-0.3+rand*0.15,-0.4-rand*0.15) circle (1pt and 0.5pt);
    }


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @J Leon V.: Image Peru-flag-russia-2018.pdf to used to get coordinates. Which software you use to get coordinates from pdf file?

Comment: I downloaded the image from the official page, then I edited it with inkscape to cut the canvas, then export it in pdf format; the program that allows me to see the coordinates is TikzEdt, start importing the image in pdf format as a background, then using the WYSIWYG mode with the cursor I found the coordinates.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `\usepackage[keli]{malayalam}`?

Comment: aha, I can mark only 1 answer for my question. Is that reasonable? I want to mark several answer in this post

Comment: what about all of the flags posted here floating in the wind?

Answer (score 52):

Some `spy` practice with completely off colors and shapes and ratios just to replicate a viral I've seen some time ago.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\definecolor{pantone 200}{RGB}{186,12,47}
\definecolor{pantone 280}{RGB}{0,32,91}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4,width=11mm, height=8mm, connect spies}]
\fill[pantone 200] (0,0) rectangle (22mm,16mm);
\draw[white, line width=4mm] (0,8mm) -- ++(22mm,0) (8mm,0) -- ++(0mm,16mm);
\draw[pantone 280, line width=2mm] (0,8mm) -- ++(22mm,0) (8mm,0) -- ++(0mm,16mm);

\spy[draw=none] on (2mm,10mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:IND}] at (-1.5,1.25);
\spy[draw=none] on (2mm,6mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:POL}] at (-1.5,0);
\spy[draw=none] on (9.5mm,3mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:FRA}] at (0,-1);
\spy[draw=none, magnification=3] on (12mm,9.5mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:NLD}] at (3,1.25);
\spy[draw=none, magnification=2] on (8.5mm,8mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:FIN}] at (1.2,2.5);
\spy[draw=none, magnification=1.5] on (18mm,8mm) in node[label={[black, label distance=-2mm]90:THA}] at (3,-0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhh, I never read about this!

Comment: @Sigur Probably because it is all made up

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooh

Comment: One tiny detail: the Netherlands is *not* participating in the FIFA World Cup... 2018 :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, Thailand, Indonesia and Finland aren't either. And percusse is in the Netherlands so I'm sure he's aware of this fact. :)

Comment: Finland's dimensions seem a bit off though.

Comment: The center piece alone warrants an upvote.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Didn't know you're from Finland ;-)

Comment: The flags of Monaco and Indonesia are almost identical. Maybe they are different in color a little bit.

Answer (score 35):

Here is the Brazilian flag [(high resolution PNG here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYLZk.png).

[image]

Informations can be found in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Brazil#Design) and [about text positioning here](https://fotw.info/flags/br.html#law2).

```
\documentclass[border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{green} {RGB}{  0,156, 59}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255,223,  0}
\definecolor{blue}  {RGB}{  0, 39,118}

\newcommand{\wstar}[2]{%
  \fill[white]
  ($#1+(234:#2)$) --
  ($#1+( 90:#2)$) --
  ($#1+(306:#2)$) --
  ($#1+(162:#2)$) --
  ($#1+( 18:#2)$) --
  cycle;
}

\newcommand{\letter}[2][0]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{%
    \resizebox{.3cm}{.33cm}{%
      \textcolor{green}{\textbf{#2}}%
}}}

\newcommand{\Eletter}[2][0]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{%
    \resizebox{.25cm}{.3cm}{%
      \textcolor{green}{\textbf{#2}}%
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

%% rectangle, losangle, circle
\fill[green]  (-10,-7) rectangle (10,7);
\fill[yellow] (0,-5.3) -- (-8.3,0) -- (0,5.3) -- (8.3,0) -- cycle;
\fill[blue]   (0,0)    circle    ( 3.5);

%% white band
\begin{scope}
    \clip        ( 0, 0) circle (3.5);
    \fill[white] (-2,-7) circle (8.5);
    \fill[blue]  (-2,-7) circle (8  );
\end{scope}

%% stars
\wstar{( 1.080, 1.100)}{0.15} % 1 Spica (α Virginis)
\wstar{(-2.860, 0.630)}{0.15} % 2 Procyon (α Canis Minoris)
\wstar{(-1.330,-0.140)}{0.12} % 3 Alphard (α Hydrae)
\wstar{( 0.950, 0.175)}{0.10} % 4 Dhanab al Shuja (γ Hydrae)
\wstar{(-2.550,-0.840)}{0.15} % 5 Sirius (α Canis Majoris)
\wstar{(-2.975,-1.155)}{0.12} % 6 Mirzam (β Canis Majoris)
\wstar{(-2.200,-0.630)}{0.07} % 7 Muliphen (γ Canis Majoris)
\wstar{(-1.820,-1.190)}{0.12} % 8 Wezen (δ Canis Majoris)
\wstar{(-1.920,-1.540)}{0.10} % 9 Adhara (ε Canis Majoris)
\wstar{(-1.405,-1.860)}{0.15} %10 Canopus (α Carinae)
\wstar{( 0.000,-0.560)}{0.12} %11 Gacrux (γ Crucis)
\wstar{(-0.351,-0.875)}{0.10} %12 Pálida (δ Crucis)
\wstar{(-0.175,-1.120)}{0.07} %13 Intrometida (ε Crucis)
\wstar{( 0.000,-1.575)}{0.15} %14 Acrux (α Crucis)
\wstar{( 0.407,-0.875)}{0.12} %15 Mimosa (β Crucis)
\wstar{( 2.455,-1.225)}{0.15} %16 Antares (α Scorpii)
\wstar{( 2.940,-1.260)}{0.10} %17 Graffias (β Scorpii)
\wstar{( 2.595,-1.535)}{0.12} %18 Wei (ε Scorpii)
\wstar{( 2.383,-1.822)}{0.12} %19 Shaula (λ Scorpii)
\wstar{( 2.100,-1.990)}{0.10} %20 Girtab (κ Scorpii)
\wstar{( 1.740,-1.930)}{0.10} %21 Denebakrab (μ Scorpii)
\wstar{( 1.755,-2.270)}{0.12} %22 Sargas (θ Scorpii)
\wstar{( 1.750,-2.625)}{0.10} %23 Apollyon (ι Scorpii)
\wstar{( 1.350,-2.050)}{0.10} %24 δ Trianguli Australis
\wstar{( 1.050,-2.356)}{0.12} %25 Atria (α Trianguli Australis)
\wstar{( 0.775,-1.960)}{0.10} %26 γ Trianguli Australis
\wstar{( 0.000,-2.740)}{0.05} %27 Polaris Australis (σ Octantis)

%% curved text 'ORDEM PROGRESSO'
\foreach \a/\l/\t in {%
  97.130000/O/ 7.130000,
  94.090000/R/ 4.090000,
  91.050000/D/ 1.050000,
  88.010000/E/-1.990000,
  84.970000/M/-5.030000,
%
  75.970000/P/-14.030000,
  72.846250/R/-17.153750,
  69.722500/O/-20.277500,
  66.598750/G/-23.401250,
  63.475000/R/-26.525000,
  60.351250/E/-29.648750,
  57.227500/S/-32.772500,
  54.103750/S/-35.896250,
  50.980000/O/-39.020000
}{%
  \node at ($(-2,-7)+(\a:8.25)$) {\letter[\t]{\l}};
}

%% curved text 'E' (smaller than other letters)
\foreach \a/\l/\t in {%
  80.470000/E/-9.530000
}{%
  \node at ($(-2,-7)+(\a:8.25)$) {\Eletter[\t]{\l}};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome work! `:)`

Comment: At least Brazil need not fear a 7:1 knockout by Germany any more ...

Comment: @PauloCereda, I think is done now!

Comment: @Sigur Fantastic! Congrats!

Comment: @Sigur really great job!

Comment: @Joseph, thanks. Maybe the curved text could be improved. It is out of my skills.

Comment: @Sigur: could you explain a bit about the way you got very "odd" numbers like this \wstar{(-2.975,-1.155)}{0.12} ?

Comment: @BlackMild, the position of star in the circle are determined according to origin (centre of circle), which was divided into equal parts. So, the numbers (in tikz units) were chosen by hand to put the stars in the right position, comparing with the official draw.

Answer (score 29):

Marmots support Iceland!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\definecolor{SkyBlue}{rgb}{0.00784314,0.32156864,0.61176473}
\fill[SkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle (25,18);
\fill[white] (7,0) rectangle (11,18);
\fill[white] (0,7) rectangle (25,11);
\definecolor{FireRed}{rgb}{0.86274511,0.11764706,0.20784314}
\fill[FireRed] (8,0) rectangle (10,18);
\fill[FireRed] (0,8) rectangle (25,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Dimensions corrected! Big thanks to @Torbjørn T.!

The dimensions are (now) in agreement with [official Iceland web site](https://www.government.is/topics/governance-and-national-symbols/icelandic-national-flag/):

[image]

As pointed out by @ShreevatsaR, the [width of a flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Glossary_of_vexillology&oldid=843772202) is not the analogue of a `\textwidth`, say, but the analogue of the `\textheight`. The dimensions there are consistent with my updated previous post, but much simpler, and have first been used in [Jürgen G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438127/121799). Really hope that this is the flag of the world cup winner in 2022! ;-)

Comment: Standard flag terminology seems to be that “width” means “vertical width” (sometimes aka “hoist”) (the “span of a flag down the side parallel to the flagpole”), and the other dimension is called the [horizontal] “length” (sometimes aka “fly”). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Glossary_of_vexillology&oldid=843772202)) So the description you quote seems to be correct and fit the image, as out of a [vertical] width of 18, the red cross indeed has [vertical] width 2, and the white strips have 1 each.

Answer (score 21):

The easy ones. Now with correct aspect ratios per country. It's a tough audience out there...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\barwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,calc,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\flagratio}[1]{\gdef\flrat{#1}\setlength{\barwidth}{\flrat pt*100/3}}
\flagratio{1}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    horizontal stripes/.style={
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3,
        draw,
        minimum width=100pt*\flrat,
        minimum height=100pt,
        rectangle split part fill={#1},
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        name=flag},
    vertical stripes/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal, 
        rectangle split parts=3,
        draw,
        minimum width=100pt*\flrat,
        minimum height=100pt,
        text width=100pt*\flrat/3,
        rectangle split part fill={#1},
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        name=flag},
    two stripes/.style={
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=2,
        draw,
        minimum width=150pt,
        minimum height=100pt,
        rectangle split part fill={#1},
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
    }
\newcommand{\vflag}[3][.5]{\flagratio{#2}\tikz[baseline]{\node[vertical stripes={#3},scale=#1](a){\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}\nodepart{three}\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}};}}
\newcommand{\hflag}[3][.5]{\flagratio{#2}\tikz[baseline]{\node[horizontal stripes={#3},scale=#1](a){\rule{0pt}{33.3pt}\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{33.3pt}\nodepart{three}\rule{0pt}{33.3pt}};}}
\newcommand{\twobar}[3][.5]{\flagratio{#2}\tikz[baseline]{\node[two stripes={#3},scale=#1](a){\rule{0pt}{50pt}\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{50pt}};}}
\newcommand{\colombia}[1][.5]{\flagratio{1.5}\tikz[baseline]{\node[horizontal stripes={ColombiaYellow,ColombiaBlue,ColombiaRed},scale=#1](a){\rule{0pt}{50pt}\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{25pt}\nodepart{three}\rule{0pt}{25pt}};}}
\newcommand{\senegal}[1][.5]{\tikz[baseline]{\node[vertical stripes={SenegalGreen,SenegalYellow,SenegalRed},scale=#1](a){\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}\nodepart{three}\rule{0pt}{\barwidth}};\node[star,fill=SenegalGreen,star point ratio=1.5,star point height=7.5pt,scale=.75] {};}}
\newcommand{\morocco}[1][.5]
{\flagratio{1.5}\tikz[baseline={(0,25pt)},scale=#1]{%
% Code here from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400055/2693
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{.5} % distance center to tip
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cc}{\ct*sin(18)/sin(126)} % distance center to corner (sine rule)
\draw[rectangle,fill=MoroccoRed] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,0pt) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick,MoroccoGreen] (75pt,50pt)
    +(90-0*36:\ct) coordinate(T1)
    foreach[evaluate=\x as \nc using int((\x+1)/2),   % number for corner coordinates
            evaluate=\x as \nt using int((\x+1)/2+1)] % number for tip coordinates
        \x in {1,3,...,9}{
        -- +(90-\x*36:\cc) coordinate(C\nc) -- +({90-(\x+1)*36}:\ct) coordinate(T\nt)}
    -- cycle;
% the rest
\draw[ultra thick,MoroccoGreen] (C1) -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (C4) -- (C5) -- cycle;}}
\newcommand{\england}[1][.5]{\flagratio{1.667}\tikz[baseline={(0pt,25pt)},scale=#1]{
\draw[rectangle] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,0pt) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=20pt*#1,EnglishRed] (0pt,50pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,50pt);
\draw[line width=20pt*#1,EnglishRed] (50pt*\flrat,0pt) -- (50pt*\flrat,100pt);
}
}
\newcommand{\sweden}[1][.5]{\flagratio{1.6}\tikz[baseline={(0pt,25pt)},scale=#1]{%
\draw[rectangle,fill=SwedishBlue] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,0pt) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=20pt*#1,SwedishYellow] (0pt,50pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,50pt);
\draw[line width=20pt*#1,SwedishYellow] (37.5pt*\flrat,0pt) -- (37.5pt*\flrat,100pt);
}
}
\newcommand{\denmark}[1][.5]{\flagratio{1.321}\tikz[baseline={(0pt,25pt)},scale=#1]{%
\draw[rectangle,fill=DanishRed] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,100pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,0pt) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=14.28pt*#1,white] (0pt,50pt) -- (100pt*\flrat,50pt);
\draw[line width=14.28pt*#1,white] (37.8pt*\flrat,0pt) -- (37.8pt*\flrat,100pt);
}
}


\definecolor[named]{NigerianGreen}{RGB}{0,135,83}
\definecolor[named]{GermanGold}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor[named]{GermanRed}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor[named]{BelgianYellow}{RGB}{253,218,36}
\definecolor[named]{BelgianRed}{RGB}{239,51,64}
\definecolor[named]{FrenchBlue}{RGB}{0,85,164}
\definecolor[named]{FrenchRed}{RGB}{239,65,53}
\definecolor[named]{RussianBlue}{RGB}{0,57,166}
\definecolor[named]{RussianRed}{RGB}{213,43,30}
\definecolor[named]{PolishRed}{RGB}{220, 20, 60}
\definecolor[named]{ColombiaYellow}{RGB}{252,209,22}
\definecolor[named]{ColombiaBlue}{RGB}{0,56,147}
\definecolor[named]{ColombiaRed}{RGB}{206,17,38}
\definecolor[named]{SenegalGreen}{RGB}{0, 133, 63}
\definecolor[named]{SenegalYellow}{RGB}{253, 239, 66}
\definecolor[named]{SenegalRed}{RGB}{227, 27, 35}
\definecolor[named]{MoroccoRed}{RGB}{193, 39, 45}
\definecolor[named]{MoroccoGreen}{RGB}{0, 98, 51}
\definecolor[named]{EnglishRed}{RGB}{207, 8, 31}
\definecolor[named]{SwedishBlue}{RGB}{45, 95, 161}
\definecolor[named]{SwedishYellow}{RGB}{255, 202, 32}
\definecolor[named]{DanishRed}{RGB}{224, 24, 54}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{30pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{1in}m{1.5in}p{1in}m{1.5in}}
France: & \vflag{1.5}{FrenchBlue,white,FrenchRed} &
Nigeria: & \vflag{2}{NigerianGreen,white,NigerianGreen}\\
Belgium: & \vflag{1.154}{black,BelgianYellow,BelgianRed} &
Russia: & \hflag{1.5}{white,RussianBlue,RussianRed}\\
Germany: & \hflag{1.667}{black,GermanRed,GermanGold} &
Poland: & \twobar{1.6}{white,PolishRed}\\
Colombia: & \colombia & 
Senegal: & \senegal \\
Morocco: & \morocco  & England & \england\\
Sweden & \sweden & Denmark & \denmark
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Your drawings do not match the official ratios. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aspect_ratios_of_national_flags

Comment: @AndréC These are 3D pictures and Alan is looking at the flags from and angle. ;-)

Comment: @AndréC See updated answer. :)

Comment: Shouldn't all flags have equal area in the name of justice?

Comment: Please add Wales. (I don't know if we're in the World Cup and I don't care. Not as if it is rugby.)

Comment: @cfr You're the second person to ask for equal areas. If someone wants to modify my answer to give all the flags equal area they are welcome to do so. But this shows the aspect ratios accurately.  As for Wales, (i) it's not in the World Cup and (ii) these are the *easy* ones. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I already said (i) is irrelevant, in my view. (ii) is, as always, the bugbear. Only now do I realise how much easier other nations' kids must have had it in primary school when asked to draw their flags! The areas was meant to be a joke, though clearly not a very original one. (Unless the first comment was serious, I guess, but that seems implausible.)

Comment: @cfr You supply the dragon and I'll do the rest. :)

Comment: Very nice now !

Comment: @marmot, here come the ducks again... quack!!

Comment: @Sigur I was actually making an effort in converting the Wales flag to [Tikz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEokz.png) but my code is too long to be uploaded, that's why I was suggesting ducks ;-)

Comment: @marmot, converting from svg I suppose. Nice flag.

Comment: @Sigur Yes. Tried to be clever and convert to pgf syntax. Well, turns out not to be short enough, though. But learned a bit when doing it.

Comment: @cfr David Carlisle (!) has done the [dragon here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45364478#45364478). With Ti*k*Z (!)

Answer (score 17):

For anyone who is interested: Save the following as `pst-flags.sty` and put it into the root path of your TeX system or just into your working folder:

```
    \ProvidesPackage{pst-flags}[2012/11/16 v. 0.01 Flags for Europe (jg)]
\RequirePackage{pst-xkey}
\RequirePackage{pst-eucl}
\RequirePackage{pstricks-add}
\SpecialCoor

\pst@addfams{pst-flags}
\define@key[psset]{pst-flags}{nation}[Germany]{\def\pst@flag@nation{#1}}
\psset{nation=Germany}

\def\pstFlag{\pst@object{pstFlag}}
\def\pstFlag@i{{\use@par\@nameuse{pst@Flag\pst@flag@nation}}}

\def\pst@FlagAustria{%
\definecolor{austriaRed}{HTML}{F5002F} %Pantone 186
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=austriaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=austriaRed](!0 10 3 div 2 mul)(15,10)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](!0 10 3 div)(!15 10 3 div 2 mul)
\psframe[linecolor=austriaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=austriaRed](0,0)(!15 10 3 div)%
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagGermany{%
\definecolor{germanRed}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{germanGold}{HTML}{FFCC00}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,9)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 3 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](0,6)(15,9)
\psframe[linecolor=germanRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=germanRed](0,3)(15,6)
\psframe[linecolor=germanGold,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=germanGold](0,0)(15,3)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagBelgium{%
\definecolor{belgiumYellow}{RGB}{255 233 54}
\definecolor{belgiumRed}{RGB}{255 15 33}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,13)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 15 Breite : 13 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](0,0)(5,13)
\psframe[linecolor=belgiumYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=belgiumYellow](5,0)(10,13)
\psframe[linecolor=belgiumRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=belgiumRed](10,0)(15,13)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagBulgaria{%
\definecolor{bulgariaRed}{HTML}{D62612}
\definecolor{bulgariaGreen}{HTML}{00966E}
\psset{unit=0.6}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,15)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 3 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,10)(25,15)
\psframe[linecolor=bulgariaGreen,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bulgariaGreen](0,5)(25,10)
\psframe[linecolor=bulgariaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bulgariaRed](0,0)(25,5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagCzechRepublic{%
\definecolor{czechRed}{HTML}{D7141A}
\definecolor{czechBlue}{HTML}{11457E}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
%% Breite 1,5 : 1.5 H\"{o}he 1 : 1
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,5)(15,10)
\psframe[linecolor=czechRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=czechRed](0,0)(15,5)
\pspolygon[linecolor=czechBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=czechBlue](0,0)(7.5,5)(0,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagDenmark{%
\definecolor{denmarkRed}{HTML}{FF173D} %Pantone 185
\psset{unit=0.4054}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(37,28)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 37 Breite : 28 H\"{o}he)
%% Breite 12 - 4 - 21 : H\"{o}he 12 - 4 - 12
\psframe[linecolor=denmarkRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=denmarkRed](0,0)(37,28)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,12)(12,12)(12,0)(16,0)(16,12)(37,12)(37,16)(16,16)(16,28)(12,28)(12,16)(0,16)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagEstonia{%
\definecolor{estoniaBlue}{RGB}{18 145 255}
\psset{unit=1.3636}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(11,7)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 11 Breite : 7 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=estoniaBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=estoniaBlue](0,3.5)(11,7)
\psframe[linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](0,0)(11,3.5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagFinland{%
\definecolor{finlandBlue}{RGB}{0 82 165}
\psset{unit=0.8333}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(18,11)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 18 Breite : 11 H\"{o}he)
%% Breite 5 - 3 - 10 : H\"{o}he 4 - 3 - 4
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(18,11)
\pspolygon[linecolor=finlandBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=finlandBlue](0,4)(5,4)(5,0)(8,0)(8,4)(18,4)(18,7)(8,7)(8,11)(5,11)(5,7)(0,7)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagFrance{%
\definecolor{frenchRed}{HTML}{EF4531}
\definecolor{frenchBlue}{HTML}{0055A4}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=frenchBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=frenchBlue](0,0)(5,10)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](5,0)(10,10)
\psframe[linecolor=frenchRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=frenchRed](10,0)(15,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagUnitedKingdom{%
\definecolor{ukRed}{RGB}{204 0 0}
\definecolor{ukBlue}{RGB}{0 0 102}
\psset{unit=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(0,0)(60,30)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=ukBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukBlue](0,0)(60,30)
\rput{26.56}(0,-3.3){%
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](-10,0)(70,6)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](-10,1)(30,3)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](30,3)(70,5)
}
\rput{-26.56}(!0 30 3.3 sub){%
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](-10,0)(70,6)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](-10,1)(30,3)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](30,3)(70,5)
}
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,10)(25,10)(25,0)(35,0)(35,10)(60,10)(60,20)(35,20)(35,30)(25,30)(25,20)(0,20)
\pspolygon[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](0,12)(27,12)(27,0)(33,0)(33,12)(60,12)(60,18)(33,18)(33,30)(27,30)(27,18)(0,18)
\end{pspicture*}}

\def\pst@FlagGreece{%
\definecolor{greeceBlue}{cmyk}{1 0.6 0 0.05}
\psset{unit=0.5555}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(27,18)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(27,18)
\multido{\iA=0+4}{5}{%
\rput(0,\iA){\psframe[linecolor=greeceBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=greeceBlue](0,0)(27,2)}
}
\psframe[linecolor=greeceBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=greeceBlue](0,18)(10,8)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,12)(4,12)(4,8)(6,8)(6,12)(10,12)(10,14)(6,14)(6,18)(4,18)(4,14)(0,14)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagHungary{%
\definecolor{hungaryRed}{HTML}{CE1126}
\definecolor{hungaryGreen}{HTML}{008751}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(30,15)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=hungaryRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=hungaryRed](0,10)(30,15)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,5)(30,10)
\psframe[linecolor=hungaryGreen,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=hungaryGreen](0,0)(30,5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagIceland{%
\definecolor{icelandBlue}{HTML}{0048E0}
\definecolor{icelandRed}{HTML}{FF0F00}
\psset{unit=0.6}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,18)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 25 Breite : 18 H\"{o}he)
%% Breite 7 - 4 - 14 : H\"{o}he 7 - 4 - 7
\psframe[linecolor=icelandBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=icelandBlue](0,0)(25,18)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,7)(7,7)(7,0)(11,0)(11,7)(25,7)(25,11)(11,11)(11,18)(7,18)(7,11)(0,11)
\pspolygon[linecolor=icelandRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=icelandRed](0,8)(8,8)(8,0)(10,0)(10,8)(25,8)(25,10)(10,10)(10,18)(8,18)(8,10)(0,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagIreland{%
\definecolor{irelandOrange}{HTML}{FF7900}
\definecolor{irelandGreen}{HTML}{009A49}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(30,15)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=irelandGreen,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=irelandGreen](0,0)(10,15)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](10,0)(20,15)
\psframe[linecolor=irelandOrange,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=irelandOrange](20,0)(30,15)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagItaly{%
\definecolor{italyRed}{RGB}{206 43 55}
\definecolor{italyWhite}{RGB}{241 242 241}
\definecolor{italyGreen}{RGB}{0 146 70}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=italyGreen,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=italyGreen](0,0)(5,10)
\psframe[linecolor=italyWhite,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=italyWhite](5,0)(10,10)
\psframe[linecolor=italyRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=italyRed](10,0)(15,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagLatvia{%
\definecolor{latviaMaroon}{HTML}{9E1B34}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(30,15)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
%% H\"{o}he 2 - 1 - 2
\psframe[linecolor=latviaMaroon,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=latviaMaroon](0,9)(30,15)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,6)(30,9)
\psframe[linecolor=latviaMaroon,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=latviaMaroon](0,0)(30,6)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagLithuania{%
\definecolor{lithuaniaYellow}{RGB}{253 185 19}
\definecolor{lithuaniaGreen}{RGB}{0 106 68}
\definecolor{lithuaniaRed}{RGB}{193 39 45}
\psset{unit=0.6}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,15)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 3 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=lithuaniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lithuaniaYellow](0,10)(25,15)
\psframe[linecolor=lithuaniaGreen,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lithuaniaGreen](0,5)(25,10)
\psframe[linecolor=lithuaniaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lithuaniaRed](0,0)(25,5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagLuxembourg{%
\definecolor{luxembourgRed}{HTML}{FF1A24} %Pantone 032
\definecolor{luxembourgBlue}{HTML}{26CFFF} %Pantone 299
\psset{unit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,3)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 3 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=luxembourgRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=luxembourgRed](0,2)(5,3)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,1)(5,2)
\psframe[linecolor=luxembourgBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=luxembourgBlue](0,0)(5,1)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagMonaco{%
\definecolor{monacoRed}{cmyk}{0 0.9 0.8 0.05}
\psset{unit=0.6}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,20)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 4 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(25,10)
\psframe[linecolor=monacoRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=monacoRed](0,10)(25,20)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagNetherlands{%
\definecolor{netherlandsRed}{HTML}{AE1C28}
\definecolor{netherlandsBlue}{HTML}{21468B}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=netherlandsRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=netherlandsRed](!0 10 3 div 2 mul)(15,10)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](!0 10 3 div)(!15 10 3 div 2 mul)
\psframe[linecolor=netherlandsBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=netherlandsBlue](0,0)(!15 10 3 div)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagNorway{%
\definecolor{norgeBlue}{HTML}{002868}
\definecolor{norgeRed}{HTML}{EF2B2D}
\psset{unit=0.6818}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(22,16)
%% Wei{\ss}er Grundrahmen \"{u}ber komplette Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 22 Breite : 16 H\"{o}he)
%% 6 - 1 - 2 - 1 - 12 Breite : 6 - 1 - 2 - 1 - 6 H\"{o}he
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(22,16)
%% Rote Felder
\psframe[linecolor=norgeRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=norgeRed](0,16)(6,10)
\psframe[linecolor=norgeRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=norgeRed](10,16)(22,10)
\psframe[linecolor=norgeRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=norgeRed](0,0)(6,6)
\psframe[linecolor=norgeRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=norgeRed](10,0)(22,6)
%% Blaue Felder
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=norgeBlue,linecolor=norgeBlue](0,7)(7,7)(7,0)(9,0)(9,7)(22,7)(22,9)(9,9)(9,16)(7,16)(7,9)(0,9)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagPoland{%
\definecolor{polandRed}{HTML}{DC143C}
\psset{unit=1.875}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(8,5)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 8 Breite : 5 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,2.5)(8,5)
\psframe[linecolor=polandRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=polandRed](0,0)(8,2.5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagRomania{%
\definecolor{romaniaBlue}{RGB}{0 43 127}
\definecolor{romaniaYellow}{RGB}{252 209 22}
\definecolor{romaniaRed}{RGB}{206 17 38}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=romaniaBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=romaniaBlue](0,0)(5,10)
\psframe[linecolor=romaniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=romaniaYellow](5,0)(10,10)
\psframe[linecolor=romaniaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=romaniaRed](10,0)(15,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagRussia{%
\definecolor{russiaBlue}{HTML}{0039A6}
\definecolor{russiaRed}{HTML}{D52B1E}
\psset{unit=0.3333}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(45,30)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,20)(45,30)
\psframe[linecolor=russiaBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=russiaBlue](0,10)(45,20)
\psframe[linecolor=russiaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=russiaRed](0,0)(45,10)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagSweden{%
\definecolor{swedenBlue}{RGB}{0 127 229}
\definecolor{swedenYellow}{RGB}{255 204 0}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
%% Breite 5 - 2 - 9 : H\"{o}he 4 - 2 - 4
\psframe[linecolor=swedenBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=swedenBlue](0,0)(15,10)
\pspolygon[linecolor=swedenYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=swedenYellow](0,4)(5,4)(5,0)(7,0)(7,4)(15,4)(15,6)(7,6)(7,10)(5,10)(5,6)(0,6)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagSwitzerland{%
\definecolor{switzerlandRed}{HTML}{FF0000}
\psset{unit=0.4689}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(32,32)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 1 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
%% Kreuz: 6 7 6 7 6 : 6 7 6 7 6
\psframe[linecolor=switzerlandRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=switzerlandRed](0,0)(32,32)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](6,13)(13,13)(13,6)(19,6)(19,13)(26,13)(26,19)(19,19)(19,26)(13,26)(13,19)(6,19)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagTurkey{%
\definecolor{turkeyRed}{HTML}{CE1126}
\psset{unit=0.55555}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(27,18)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\pnode(9,9){M1}
\pnode(4.5,9){A1}
\pnode(!9 1 16 div 18 mul add 9){M2}
\pnode(!9 1 16 div 18 mul add 1 5 div 18 mul sub 9){A2}
\psframe[linecolor=turkeyRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=turkeyRed](0,0)(27,18)
\pscircle[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](M1){4.5}
\pscircle[linecolor=turkeyRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=turkeyRed](M2){!1 5 div 18 mul}
\pnode(0,9){A}
\pnode(27,9){B}
\pstInterCC[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{M1}{A1}{M2}{A2}{S1}{S2}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{A}{B}{S1}{S2}{D}
\rput(D){\rput(2.25,0){%
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](2.25;180)(2.25;-36)(2.25;108)(2.25;252)(2.25;36)
}}
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagUkraine{%
\definecolor{ukraineBlue}{HTML}{005BBB}
\definecolor{ukraineYellow}{HTML}{FFD500}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=ukraineBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukraineBlue](0,5)(15,10)
\psframe[linecolor=ukraineYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukraineYellow](0,0)(15,5)
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagUnitedStates{%
\definecolor{USred}{HTML}{B22234}
\definecolor{USblue}{HTML}{3C3B6E}
\psset{unit=0.789}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(19,10)
%% White Background = Proportion of the flag
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=USred,linecolor=USred,linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt](0,0)(19,10)
%% 6 white stripes: 13 stripes alternating red (7) and white (6)
\multido{\rA=0.769+1.538}{6}{%
\rput(0,\rA){\psframe[fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt,fillcolor=white](0,0)(!19 10 13 div)}
}
%%Blue rectangle in the upper left (Union)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=USblue,linecolor=USblue](!0 6 13 div 10 mul)(!2 5 div 19 mul 10)
%%PENTAGRAMM
\def\star{%
\def\outer{0.308}
\pnode(\outer;90){A}
\pnode(\outer;162){B}
\pnode(\outer;234){C}
\pnode(\outer;306){D}
\pnode(\outer;18){E}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt]
(A)(C)(E)(B)(D)(A)
}
%% Arrangment of the stars
%% 5 lines with 6 stars
\multido{\rV=9.462+-1.076}{5}{%
\multido{\rL=0.633+1.266}{6}{%
\rput(\rL,\rV){\star}
}}
%% 4 lines with 5 stars
\multido{\rV=8.924+-1.076}{4}{%
\multido{\rL=1.266+1.266}{5}{%
\rput(\rL,\rV){\star}
}}
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagMacedonia{%
\definecolor{macedoniaRed}{HTML}{D20000}
\definecolor{macedoniaYellow}{HTML}{FFE600}
\psset{unit=0.5357}
\begin{pspicture}(-14,-7)(14,7)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=macedoniaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaRed](-14,-7)(14,7)
\pspolygon[linecolor=macedoniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaYellow](1.4,7)(-1.4,7)(1.4,-7)(-1.4,-7)
\pspolygon[linecolor=macedoniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaYellow](14,-1.4)(14,1.4)(-14,-1.4)(-14,1.4)
\pspolygon[linecolor=macedoniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaYellow](-14,-7)(-9.8,-7)(9.8,7)(14,7)
\pspolygon[linecolor=macedoniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaYellow](14,-7)(9.8,-7)(-9.8,7)(-14,7)
\pscircle[linecolor=macedoniaRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaRed](0,0){2.5}
\pscircle[linecolor=macedoniaYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=macedoniaYellow](0,0){2}
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagEuropeanUnion{%
\definecolor{euBlue}{HTML}{003399}
\definecolor{euYellow}{HTML}{FFCC00}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 3 Breite : 2 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=euBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=euBlue](0,0)(15,10)
\def\eurostar{%
\def\outer{0.5555}
\pnode(\outer;90){A}
\pnode(\outer;162){B}
\pnode(\outer;234){C}
\pnode(\outer;306){D}
\pnode(\outer;18){E}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=euYellow,linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt]
(A)(C)(E)(B)(D)(A)
}
\rput(7.5,5){%
\multido{\iA=0+30}{12}{%
\rput(3.333;\iA){\eurostar}
}}
\end{pspicture}}

\def\pst@FlagBosniaHerzegovina{%
\definecolor{bhBlue}{HTML}{0053A1}
\definecolor{bhYellow}{HTML}{FFD911}
\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture*}(0,0)(20,10)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 2 Breite : 1 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=bhBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bhBlue](0,0)(20,10)
\pspolygon[linecolor=bhYellow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bhYellow](5.3,10)(15.3,0)(15.3,10)
\def\bhstar{%
\def\outer{0.95}
\pnode(\outer;90){A}
\pnode(\outer;162){B}
\pnode(\outer;234){C}
\pnode(\outer;306){D}
\pnode(\outer;18){E}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt]
(A)(C)(E)(B)(D)(A)
}
\multido{\rA=0+1.25}{9}{
\rput(!13.4 \rA\space sub 0.12 \rA\space add){\bhstar}}
\end{pspicture*}}

\def\pst@FlagScotland{%
\definecolor{scotlandBlue}{HTML}{0072C6} %Pantone 300
\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture*}(0,0)(20,12)
%% Flagge (Verh\"{a}ltnis 5 Breite : 3 H\"{o}he)
\psframe[linecolor=scotlandBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=scotlandBlue](0,0)(20,12)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,1.5)(0,0)(2.5,0)(20,10.5)(20,12)(17.5,12)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,10.5)(0,12)(2.5,12)(20,1.5)(20,0)(17.5,0)
\end{pspicture*}}

\endinput
```

The following will then be a not so minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-flags}

\parindent0pt
\parskip7pt

\begin{document}

The default is \verb!nation=Germany!.

Possible values for \texttt{nation} are:

\texttt{Austria, Belgium, BosniaHerzegovina, Bulgaria, CzechRepublic, Denmark, Estonia, EuropeanUnion, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Monaco, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Romania, Russia, Scotland, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, Ukraine, UnitedKingdom, UnitedStates}

\psset{unit=3.4mm,linewidth=0pt}

\pstFlag

\pstFlag[nation=Austria]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Belgium]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Bulgaria]

\pstFlag[nation=CzechRepublic]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Denmark]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Estonia]

\pstFlag[nation=Finland]\quad\pstFlag[nation=France]\quad\pstFlag[nation=UnitedKingdom]

\pstFlag[nation=Greece]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Hungary]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Iceland]

\pstFlag[nation=Ireland]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Italy]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Latvia]

\pstFlag[nation=Lithuania]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Luxembourg]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Monaco]

\pstFlag[nation=Netherlands]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Norway]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Poland]

\pstFlag[nation=Romania]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Russia]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Sweden]

\pstFlag[nation=Switzerland]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Turkey]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Ukraine]

\pstFlag[nation=BosniaHerzegovina]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Macedonia]\quad\pstFlag[nation=Scotland]

\pstFlag[nation=EuropeanUnion]\quad\pstFlag[nation=UnitedStates]


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No FlagPortugal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Portugal) ?!!!

Answer (score 12):

The most-difficult-to-create flag in the world.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linecolor=red](3,2)
    \qdisk(1.5,1){.6}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: As I was born with complete achromatopsia, the selected colors might be wrong. Feel free to update as many as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

... Turkey -- the `PSTricks` way ... a more tricky one -- for whom it may interest ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\definecolor{turkeyRed}{HTML}{CE1126}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.25}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(27,18)
%% Flagge (Verhältnis 3 Breite : 2 Höhe)
\pnode(9,9){M1}
\pnode(4.5,9){A1}
\pnode(!9 1 16 div 18 mul add 9){M2}
\pnode(!9 1 16 div 18 mul add 1 5 div 18 mul sub 9){A2}
\psframe[linecolor=turkeyRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=turkeyRed](0,0)(27,18)
\pscircle[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](M1){4.5}
\pscircle[linecolor=turkeyRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=turkeyRed](M2){!1 5 div 18 mul}
\pnode(0,9){A}
\pnode(27,9){B}
\pstInterCC[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{M1}{A1}{M2}{A2}{S1}{S2}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{A}{B}{S1}{S2}{D}
\rput(D){\rput(2.25,0){%
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](2.25;180)(2.25;-36)(2.25;108)(2.25;252)(2.25;36)
}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

... PS-Iceland ...

```
    \documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\definecolor{icelandBlue}{HTML}{0048E0}
\definecolor{icelandRed}{HTML}{FF0F00}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=0.25}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,18)
%% Flagge (Verhältnis 25 Breite : 18 Höhe)
%% Breite 7 - 4 - 14 : Höhe 7 - 4 - 7
\psframe[linecolor=icelandBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=icelandBlue](0,0)(25,18)
\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,7)(7,7)(7,0)(11,0)(11,7)(25,7)(25,11)(11,11)(11,18)(7,18)(7,11)(0,11)
\pspolygon[linecolor=icelandRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=icelandRed](0,8)(8,8)(8,0)(10,0)(10,8)(25,8)(25,10)(10,10)(10,18)(8,18)(8,10)(0,10)
%\psgrid
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Are these the correct dimensions?

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, my country went out at group stage :(. But we can still have the Australian flag here!

## Features

- Real PANTONE spot colours!
- Lazy clipping :)

## Code

I hope I got all the stupid ratios right…

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[illuminant=d50]{colorspace}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE-185-C}{PANTONE 185 C}[alt=lab]%
  {49.78,77.43,49.23/0.0,0.93,0.79,0.0}
\definespotcolor{PANTONE-280-C}{PANTONE 280 C}[alt=lab]%
  {15.12,15.25,-46.45/1.0,0.85,0.05,0.22}
\definecolor{white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\newlength\fw\setlength{\fw}{10cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    commonwealth/.style={star, star points=7, star point ratio=2.25, fill=white,
      minimum width=0.3\fw},
    alpha/.style={commonwealth, minimum size=1/7*\fw},
    beta/.style={alpha},
    gamma/.style={alpha},
    delta/.style={alpha},
    epsilon/.style={commonwealth, star points=5, minimum size=1/12*\fw},
    stgeorgebg/.style={white, line width=1/6*\fw},
    stgeorge/.style={PANTONE-185-C, line width=0.1\fw},
    standrew/.style={white, line width=0.1\fw},
    stpatrick/.style={PANTONE-185-C, line width=1/15*\fw}
  ]
  \fill [PANTONE-280-C] (0,0) rectangle (2\fw,\fw);
  \node [commonwealth] at (0.5\fw,0.25\fw) {};
  \node [alpha] at (1.5\fw,1/6*\fw) {};
  \node [beta] at (1.25\fw,0.5625\fw) {};
  \node [gamma] at (1.5\fw,5/6*\fw) {};
  \node [delta] at (31/18*\fw,151/240*\fw) {};
  \node [epsilon] at (1.6\fw,11/24*\fw) {};
  \clip (0,0.5\fw) rectangle (\fw,\fw);
  \draw [standrew] (0,0.5\fw) -- (\fw,\fw);
  \draw [standrew] (0,\fw) -- (\fw,0.5\fw);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,\fw) -- (\fw,0.5\fw) -- (\fw,0.75\fw) -- (0,0.75\fw) -- cycle;
    \draw [stpatrick] (0,\fw) -- (\fw,0.5\fw);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0.5\fw) -- (\fw,\fw) -- (0.5\fw,\fw) -- (0.5\fw,0.5\fw) -- cycle;
    \draw [stpatrick] (0,0.5\fw) -- (\fw,\fw);
  \end{scope}
  \draw [stgeorgebg] (0,0.75\fw) -- (\fw,0.75\fw);
  \draw [stgeorgebg] (0.5\fw,0.5\fw) -- (0.5\fw,\fw);
  \draw [stgeorge] (0,0.75\fw) -- (\fw,0.75\fw);
  \draw [stgeorge] (0.5\fw,0.5\fw) -- (0.5\fw,\fw);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Well, you guys are not planning to participate 2022, do you? So there is time. ;-)

Comment: Haha. @marmot, actually, for flag waving you should use rgb colours and not spot colours with the `colorspace` package. I'll look up the colours for you.

Comment: @marmot, RGB colours: Blue is #00008B, red is #FF0000 and white is #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 6):

... here we go Great Britain with `PSTricks` ...

```
    \documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\definecolor{ukRed}{RGB}{204 0 0}
\definecolor{ukBlue}{RGB}{0 0 102}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture*}(0,0)(60,30)
%% Flagge (Verhältnis 2 Breite : 1 Höhe)
\def\diag{%
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](-10,0)(70,6)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](-10,1)(30,3)
\psframe[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](30,3)(70,5)
}

\psframe[linecolor=ukBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukBlue](0,0)(60,30)
\rput{26.56}(0,-3.3){\diag}
\rput{-26.56}(!0 30 3.3 sub){\diag}

\pspolygon[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,10)(25,10)(25,0)(35,0)(35,10)(60,10)(60,20)(35,20)(35,30)(25,30)(25,20)(0,20)
\pspolygon[linecolor=ukRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ukRed](0,12)(27,12)(27,0)(33,0)(33,12)(60,12)(60,18)(33,18)(33,30)(27,30)(27,18)(0,18)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Except in football, GB don't compete...so just remove all the blue and the diagonal red. :)

Comment: If they compete or not -- isn't it the founder football nation ;-)

Comment: @AlanMunn Remove all the red and all axis-aligned white :)

Comment: It isn't A nation. That's the point. GB = 3 nations. UK = 4 or 3 and part of 1, depending on your political view.

Comment: You want the flag of England.

Comment: GB vs UK vs Eng aside, this can be used as a contribution towards the Australian flag.  After all, the Australia team were, for about half a match, a chance for making the round of 16.  (We suck at Soccer)

Answer (score 6):

I think this FIFA thing is some kind of cup of sports. Anyway I do not care and chose to spam my own country's flag, Dannebrog from Denmark here:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\definecolor{DannebrogRed}{RGB}{224, 24, 54}
\fill[DannebrogRed] (0,0) rectangle (34,28);
\fill[white] (12,0) rectangle (16,28);
\fill[white] (0,12) rectangle (34,16);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dannebrog]

made with color and dimensions from: https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dannebrog.
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Denmark.

Dannebrog is the oldest continuously used national flag from app. year 1208. A popular legend tells that the flag fell from the sky during a battle as a sign from the gods.

**EDIT:**

Now implemented as four red squares on a white background instead of a white cross on a red background. -as I was unhappy about the artifacts made by viewer and rasterization.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\definecolor{DannebrogRed}{RGB}{224, 24, 54}
\fill[white] (0,0) rectangle (34,28);
\fill[DannebrogRed] (0,0) rectangle (12,12);
\fill[DannebrogRed] (16,0) rectangle (34,12);
\fill[DannebrogRed] (0,16) rectangle (12,28);
\fill[DannebrogRed] (16,16) rectangle (34,28);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Improved Dannebrog]

Comment: Judging by all the nordic flags, those gods need safety trainings and proper toolbelts to avoid dropping stuff onto peoples' heads.

Comment: Do you also have the porcine version? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Protest_Pig https://www.zoo-hannover.de/de/tiere/tier-lexikon/rotbuntes-husumer-protestschwein

Comment: I thought it looked shorter than usual but this is actually the shortest legal version.

Comment: @pipe - The wikipedia is actually a bit confusing. -one can be led to believe that the dimensions within the interval can be chosen totally free. That is not true. The reason the flag is elongated with a 'slidkant' on the right side, is so that there is extra material to cut off when a *cloth flag* becomes torn. Also the side away from the pole of a *cloth flag* seem smaller when waving in the wind - and therefore looks nicer when extended.

Answer (score 6):

For whom it might be of interest ...

Some more fun, using the font `CountriesOfEurope`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}      % PSTricks package for filling/tiling
\usepackage{pst-text}              % PSTricks package for character path
\usepackage[scaled=60]{CountriesOfEurope}

\def\tricolore{%
\definecolor{frenchRed}{HTML}{EF4531}
\definecolor{frenchBlue}{HTML}{0055A4}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
%% Flagge (Verhältnis 3 Breite : 2 Höhe)
\psframe[linecolor=frenchBlue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=frenchBlue](0,0)(5,10)
\psframe[linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](5,0)(10,10)
\psframe[linecolor=frenchRed,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=frenchRed](10,0)(15,10)
\end{pspicture}
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(18,20)
\psset{boxfillsize={(-0.75\linewidth,-22cm)(0.5\linewidth,15cm)}}
\psboxfill{\psset{unit=20mm}\pspicture(10,10)\tricolore\endpspicture}
\centerline{\pscharpath[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,addfillstyle=boxfill,fillangle=0,fillsep=1mm]{\rput[b](0,-1){\EUCountry{140}}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is now a package [worldflags – Drawing flags with TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/worldflags) which now allows you to obtain the flags of countries around the world.

It can be used directly in the document as shown in the documentation:

> A particular flag is selected via a parameter; for national flags that is the two-letter country code (i. e. the domain name).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{worldflags}

\begin{document}
\worldflag{CH}  
\end{document}
```

[image: swiss flag]

Or inserted in a tikz environment like a \pic with or without options.

Here is an example from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\def\w{30}
\def\d{20}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{flagpole}
{30mm}{color(0mm)=(white);
color(1mm)=(brown); color(2mm)=(black)}
\flagsdefault[width=15mm,hang=20]
\pic (gb) [country=JP,rotate=-\w] at (\d,0) {worldflag};
\pic (us) [country=FR,rotate=\w,turn=180] at (-\d,0) {worldflag};
\fill [shading=flagpole,shading angle=-\w,rotate around={-\w:(gb-nw)}]
(gb-nw)-|++(-2,-60)-|cycle;
\fill [shading=flagpole,shading angle=\w,rotate around={\w:(us-nw)}](us-nw)-|++(2,-60)-|cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: France -Japon]

Answer (score 3):

An exercise using the `l3draw` package (plus the `l3fp` and the `l3color` packages) to construct the flag of the PR China with geometry and colors adhering to official standards (although their teams have never gone far in the cup ...):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \draw_begin:

        \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 238 , 28 , 37 }
        \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 30cm , 20cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

        \cs_new:Nn \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn {
            \draw_path_scope_begin:
                \draw_transform_shift:n { #1 } 
                \draw_transform_rotate:n { 90 + #2 }
                \color_fill:nn { RGB } { #3 }
                \draw_path_moveto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } {  72 } }
                \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } { 216 } }
                \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } {   0 } }
                \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } { 144 } }
                \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } { 288 } }
                \draw_path_close:
                \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
            \draw_path_scope_end:
        }

        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 5cm , 15cm } { 0 } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 3cm } 

        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 + asind ( 3 / 5 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 10cm , 18cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 + asind ( 1 / 7 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 12cm , 16cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 - asind ( 2 / 7 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 12cm , 13cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 - asind ( 4 / 5 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 10cm , 11cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
    
    \draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using another way to create the five-pointed stars without overlapping paths:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \draw_begin:

        \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 238 , 28 , 37 }
        \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 30cm , 20cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

        \fp_const:Nn \l_myflag_radiusratio_fp { 2 / ( 3 + sqrt(5) ) }
        \cs_new:Nn \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn {
            \draw_path_scope_begin:
                \draw_transform_shift:n { #1 } 
                \draw_transform_rotate:n { 90 + #2 }
                \color_fill:nn { RGB } { #3 }
                \draw_path_moveto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } { 0 } }
                \fp_step_inline:nnnn { 72 } { 72 } { 360 } {
                    \draw_path_lineto:n 
                        { \draw_point_polar:nn { \l_myflag_radiusratio_fp * #4 } { ##1 - 36 } }
                    \fp_compare:nNnF { ##1 } = { 360 } {
                        \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #4 } { ##1 } }
                    }
                }
                \draw_path_close:
                \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
            \draw_path_scope_end:
        }

        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 5cm, 15cm } { 0 } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 3cm } 

        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 + asind ( 3 / 5 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 10cm, 18cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 + asind ( 1 / 7 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 12cm, 16cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 - asind ( 2 / 7 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 12cm, 13cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 90 - asind ( 4 / 5 ) }
        \myflag_fivepointedstar:nnnn { 10cm, 11cm } { \l_tmpa_fp } 
            { 255 , 255 , 0 } { 1cm } 
    
    \draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the [construction sheet found on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Canada_(construction_sheet_-_leaf_geometry).svg). In order to simplify the calculations for the notches, I created a to-path that does all the math:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    maple leaf notch/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        to path={
            \pgfextra{
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\delta}{atan2(
                    array({\tikztotarget},1)-array({\tikztostart},1),
                    array({\tikztotarget},0)-array({\tikztostart},0)
                )}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{\delta-#1}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{#2-\delta}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\gamma}{180-\alpha-\beta}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{veclen(
                    array({\tikztotarget},1)-array({\tikztostart},1),
                    array({\tikztotarget},0)-array({\tikztostart},0)
                )}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ac}{sin(\beta)*\ab/sin(\gamma)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\bc}{sin(\alpha)*\ab/sin(\gamma)}
            }
            { [rounded corners=#3] -- +(#1:\ac) }
            -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]

    \fill[white] (-960,-480) rectangle (960,480);

    \fill[red] (-480,-480) rectangle (-960,480);
    \fill[red] (480,-480) rectangle (960,480);

    \fill[red] (-18,-406) 
        to[maple leaf notch={87:10:19}] (-203,-244)
        to[maple leaf notch={70:321:13}] (-372,-13)
        to[maple leaf notch={35:288:13}] (-360,137)
        to[maple leaf notch={348:247:13}] (-216,171)
        to[maple leaf notch={313:281:13}] (-150,302)
        to[maple leaf notch={330:243:13}] (0,400)
        to[maple leaf notch={297:210:13}] (150,302)
        to[maple leaf notch={259:227:13}] (216,171)
        to[maple leaf notch={293:192:13}] (360,137)
        to[maple leaf notch={252:155:13}] (372,-13)
        to[maple leaf notch={219:110:13}] (203,-244)
        to[maple leaf notch={170:93:19}] (18,-406)
        -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]